# How do I include react elements dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

I have several elements whose names all end in "Page" and I'm passing as a prop an array of strings that contain the start of those names.
I'm importing elements like HomePage, AboutPage, ContactsPage and I have available as a prop an array of strings that looks like: ['Home', 'About', 'Contact', ...]
How can I map over the array and render the elements?

I tried string interpolation and I can produce the right names of the components, but the components themselves don't get rendered. My latest attempt was this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Pages.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import HomePage from '../../pages/HomePage/HomePage';
import AboutPage from '../../pages/AboutPage/AboutPage';
import ProjectsPage from '../../pages/ProjectsPage/ProjectsPage';
import SkillsPage from '../../pages/SkillsPage/SkillsPage';
import LearningPage from '../../pages/LearningPage/LearningPage';

const Pages = ({ pages }) => {
  Pages.propTypes = {
    pages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  return (
    <div className="Pages">
      {
        pages.map((page) => {
          const ComponentName = `${page}Page`;
          return <ComponentName />;
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pages;
```

I wanted to render the components ,  etc but instead I'm rendering a "ComponentName" component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically load using [import()](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) or lazily import using [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), which still requires the dynamic `import()`.

I will show you how to load component lazily in this answer dynamically.

Steps required are,
1. Create a method that accepts a name of page and load dynamically.
2. Wrap the dynamically loaded Pages with `<Suspense />`
3. Load page components dynamically

### 1. Create a method that accepts a name of page and load dynamically.

```
const loadPage = page => lazy(() => import(`./pages/${page}Page`));
```

*You don't necessarily need to use `lazy` but the principle is the same. (You just don't need `Suspense`)*

### 2. Wrap the dynamically loaded Pages with `<Suspense />`

```
const pageNames = ["Home", "About", "Contact"];
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Pages pages={pageNames} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you mentioned, you already have a list of `pages` you can pass to `Pages` so pass it to `<Pages pages={pageNames} />` and wrap it with [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense).

### 3. Load page components dynamically

This is where the magic and fun stuff happens

```
function Pages({ pages }) {
  return (
    <ol>
      {pages.map(page => {
        const Page = loadPage(page);
        return (
          <li key={page}>
            <Page />
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

From the step #1, we have `loadPage`, which loads a page component dynamically.

```
const loadPage = page => lazy(() => import(`./pages/${page}Page`));
```

*Shown one more time as a reference.*

For each page, you load a page, assigning it to `Page` ([capitalize the first letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type)) and simply instantiate it (`<Page />`).

That's all it takes to load components dynamically.

You can find the working demo here.
[image: Edit so.answer.57233711]

### Shameless Plug.

If you want to dig deeper, I have written two posts on how to load components dynamically.

1. [Loading React Components Dynamically on Demand](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2017/12/03/loading-react-components-dynamically-demand/)
2. [Loading React Components Dynamically on Demand using React.lazy](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/10/28/loading-react-components-dynamically-on-demand-using-react-lazy/)

Answer (score 1):

map component with componentName, then you can return corresponding correct

```
import React from 'react';
import './Pages.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import HomePage from '../../pages/HomePage/HomePage';
import AboutPage from '../../pages/AboutPage/AboutPage';
import ProjectsPage from '../../pages/ProjectsPage/ProjectsPage';
import SkillsPage from '../../pages/SkillsPage/SkillsPage';
import LearningPage from '../../pages/LearningPage/LearningPage';

const routerMap = {
  'pageabout': <AboutPage/>,
  'pagehome': <HomePage/>,
}

const Pages = ({ pages }) => {
  Pages.propTypes = {
    pages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  return (
    <div className="Pages">
      {
        pages.map((page) => {
          const ComponentName = `${page}Page`;
          return routerMap[ComponentName ];
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pages;
```

Comment: You have missed the `key` prop!!

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that add code duplication? With this solution the props are not used. And if I wanted to change the order of the pages or add new ones, it's a little inconvenient. The point of using props was so I only had to edit the list of pages in one place (props that I'm passing)